# Create VM from old HDD containing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, physical-to-virtual

I used to have a standalone server running Ubuntu Server on a 1TB HDD which is now removed and replaced with an ESXI host OS.
What I would like to do is to turn the old HDD with Ubuntu Server on into a vm which is hosted on the same computer it used to sit in.

I've tried to look for a fitting solution, but none seem to match my needs.

Is there some way I can connect the old HDD to my client, make it a vm and move it to the ESXI-host? I could also connect it to the host if that's easier.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try ```sudo qemu-img convert -c -f raw -O [vmdk|qcow2] /dev/sd<oldhdd>  newdisk.[vmdk|qcow2]```, then import it to your server, should work.. i guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Windows, image the harddisk (using `dd` or such) and import the image via VMware Converter directly to the host.